# Programmatically find payments to vendor bills

Tags: java, netsuite

I have a vendor bill, let's say `#12345`

It has a bill payment `11111`, that has `X` amount applied to it, and bill payment `22222` that has `Y` amount applied to it *(leading to the bill being paid in full)*.

How do I create a webservices query to get back `11111` and `22222`?

Right now, in java, I'm doing:

```
SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest();
TransactionSearch ts = new TransactionSearch();
TransactionSearchBasic tsb = new TransactionSearchBasic();

SearchMultiSelectField smsf = new SearchMultiSelectField();
smsf.setOperator(SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.ANY_OF);
RecordRef rr = new RecordRef();
rr.setType(RecordType.VENDOR_BILL);
rr.setInternalId(inv.getNetSuiteID());
smsf.getSearchValue().add(rr);
tsb.setAppliedToTransaction(smsf);
ts.setBasic(tsb);
sr.setSearchRecord(ts);
```

Which, in plain language, just searches for transactions that have an applied to transaction value of the vendor bill (`12345`).  But this query returns `0` records. *(Same code, and searching for internal IDs work just fine, so it's the query construction that is at fault here, not the actual operation of the webservices.)*

What's the actual field I'm supposed to search by?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching under what the field linking these is, normally child records have the parent linked. You can search bill payments originated from #12345 and that should spit both payments. You'll have to search on the records themselves for the field name as I don't have an account at hand to confirm.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean.  I thought that the parent-child relationship between those two is the "applied to transaction" field? Is there another field linking them?

Comment: The easiest way to find links IMHO is to go to the record on the UI, open the console (f11 on chrome) and type: var rec = nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId()) ... then see what's inside rec.fields, if you see the internal I'd of the parent record, that's your link.